# tinymce trigger html validation

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm adding html to the tinymce editor through javascipt. After adding the html I wand tinymce to validate the added html with the build in html validator against the valid_elements. Which js function to I have to call to run the validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called mceCleanup. You need to call

```
ed.execCommand('mceCleanup'); // ed is the editor instance you get calling tinymce.get('your_editor_id')
```